# Curious relations between numbers

Tags: number-theory

Lets  have the numbers $454+2\sqrt{457}, 16+8\sqrt{85}, 460+4\sqrt{457}, 83+\sqrt{85}, 14\sqrt{457}+42 , 87+3\sqrt{85}$.

1. How are these numbers related?
2. How are such numbers generated?

HINT 1:

What are the relations between the numbers 5, 13, 17....

ΗΙΝΤ 2:

Let's have a triangle $ABC$ where $AB=87+3\sqrt{85}$ and $BC=16+8\sqrt{85}$ and $AC=83+\sqrt{85}$. What are the relations between the sides of the triangle $ABC$?

HINT 3:

What would be an extension of the Pythagorean theorem?

Comment: Are the commas separators between the numbers?  Eg, the first number is "454 + 2*sqrt(457)"?

Comment: Yes the commas separate the numbers. The first is (454+2√457).

Comment: 1. Any of them can be turned into any other by replacing certain positive integers with others. 2. By writing down something of the form "a + b sqrt(c)" where a,b,c are positive integers. ... Obviously this is not the answer you intend, and some commonalities beyond the ones I have mentioned here are apparent. But at the moment this seems too much a "guess what I'm thinking" puzzle.

Comment: Are these _all_ the numbers of a particular sort? If so, then figuring out what condition it is that separates these numbers from all others would be a well-defined puzzle. (I guess they are _not_ all the numbers of whatever kind you have in mind.)

Comment: Or could you, after the fashion of ["word-property" puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-property), give some examples of numbers that look a bit like yours but _aren't_ of the relevant kind? For instance, $17+21\sqrt{29}$ has a few things in common with your numbers; does it belong on the list or not?

Comment: The numbers have to stay as they are. We can create infinitely many of this type of number. Keep in mind that when you create new numbers of  this type, there is a fundamental rule that applies.The trick is to find the fundamental rule that connects these numbers.  17+21√29 does not belong.

Comment: My point is that there are _many_ possible fundamental rules, especially when all we have is positive examples. (We do have _one_ negative example now, which is nice.) Or maybe I'm misunderstanding and this is a _sequence_ of numbers rather than a _set_; in that case I take back most of what I said above, because presumably there will only be one reasonable candidate rule. Is this the start of a _sequence_ or some elements of a _set_?

Comment: 1. Is the order the numbers are written important ? 2. Is there a reason for writing "14√(457)+42" and not "42+14√(457)" ?

Comment: @ Gareth  McCaughan   ΗINT: What are the relations between  the numbers  5,13,17, .............and so on

Comment: If you meant for the triangle ABC mentioned in the last line to be a right triangle, [it isn't](https://www.calculator.net/triangle-calculator.html?vc=&vx=89.75636&vy=92.21954&va=&vz=114.6586&vb=&angleunits=d&x=77&y=28)

Comment: @Ross Presser. The triangle  ABC is not  a right  triangle.

Comment: @VassilisParassidis: Eight weeks later, no winners. Can we have the real answer now?

Answer (score 4):

**Possible answer**

Considering hint 2,

> some obvious things to do given the side-lengths of a triangle are to calculate its area and to calculate the angles, or more straightforwardly their cosines. For both of the obvious triples into which the six given numbers may be divided, there's nothing obviously interesting about the area but there *is* something interesting about the angle-cosines: **one of them is rational, and the other two are an irrational number and minus its conjugate**. So for the "457-numbers" we get $\frac{15}{19}$ and $\frac1{133}\left(\pm17+2\sqrt{457}\right)$, and for the "85-numbers" we get $\frac{9}{14}$ and $\frac{1}{112}\left(\pm23+5\sqrt{85}\right)$.

So perhaps this is the condition Vassilis has in mind? It is equivalent to

> $\alpha\mathrel{:=}\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}$ being rational, while $\beta\mathrel{:=}\frac{c^2+a^2-b^2}{2ca}$ and $\gamma\mathrel{:=}\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab}$ have the property that $\beta\gamma$ and $\beta-\gamma$ are rational.

One can arrange for these to hold without too much pain, and thus construct other (kinda-)examples.

> Given $p\mathrel{:=}\beta\gamma$ and $q\mathrel{:=}\beta-\gamma$, we can find $\beta,-\gamma$ as the roots of the quadratic $t^2-qt-p=0$; then it happens that the condition $\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2+2\alpha\beta\gamma=1$ must hold (this is a consequence of the fact that the angles of a triangle add up to $\pi$)), so we can solve a quadratic equation for $\alpha$ (for which we don't actually need to have found $\beta,\gamma$; that relation is equivalent to $\alpha^2+2p\alpha+q^2+2p-1=0$; we might prefer to pick $\alpha,q$ first and deduce $p$, to ensure that all three are rational); and then we can pick $a$ arbitrarily and then set $b=\frac{1-\beta^2}{\alpha\beta+\gamma}a$ and $c=\alpha b+\beta a$. This will make all of $a,b,c$ elements of the same quadratic field, if we choose $a$ appropriately; but, alas, it won't automatically make them algebraic integers. (What does "appropriately" mean? Well, $\beta,\gamma$ are of form $u+v\sqrt{q^2+4p}$ with $u,v$ rational, so we should choose $a$ to be of that form too.)

However,

> it is not obvious to me whether the triangle-condition I've found is *all* that is meant to be special about these numbers; and my way of constructing triples satisfying the conditions doesn't automatically produce *integers*. Neither (I think) does it automatically produce side-lengths that satisfy the triangle inequality, for that matter. Not producing integers is actually fairly easy to resolve, because our condition on the cosines is unaltered by scaling all of $a,b,c$ by any constant, so we can just multiply them all by something that clears all the denominators. What about the triangle inequality? I think it suffices to make sure that $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are all between $-1$ and $+1$. We get to choose $\alpha$. To make $\beta,\gamma$ fall into that range it suffices to ensure that the quadratic expression whose roots are to get $\beta,-\gamma$ is positive at $-1$ and at $+1$; that is, that $1\pm q-p>0$ for both choices of sign; that is, that $p+|q|<1$; that is, that $\frac{1-\alpha^2-q^2}{2(1+\alpha)}+|q|<1$; this will be true provided $q<\frac{1+\alpha}2$.

With these refinements

> we have arranged to guarantee that the angle conditions I have described hold, and that the algebraic numbers in our triple are integers belonging to the same quadratic field. Of course this doesn't guarantee that I have found the *same* property Vassilis was thinking of. For that, I would need to be able to read his mind.

Here's a worked example.

> Let's take $\alpha=1/4$ and $q=1/2$; then $p=\frac{1-\alpha^2-q^2}{2(1+\alpha)}=\frac{11}{40}$. Now our discriminant $q^2+4p$ is $27/20$, which is a square times $15$, so everything is going to live in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{15})$; let's take $a=2+\sqrt{15}$. Then $b=\frac{1-\beta^2}{\alpha\beta+\gamma}a=\frac{13+\sqrt{15}}5$, and $c=\alpha b+\beta a=\frac{17+3\sqrt{15}}5$. We have a bunch of 5s in the denominators, so multiply all of $a,b,c$ by 5, so now they're all integers and the cosines are unaltered. Then $\cos A=\frac14$, and $\cos B=\frac1{20}\left(5+3\sqrt{15}\right)$, and $\cos C=\frac1{20}\left(-5+3\sqrt{15}\right)$. Everything works out nicely.

Comment: This not the answer. I  will add another HINT and I hope after that you will think more creatively.......

Answer (score 2):

I see digits that nearly involve $42$ written as $40 + (1 + 1) ---> 411$, in a symmetrical manner.  Forward, or backward, $4$'s with $1$'s.

$454 = 227(2) = [114(2)-1]2 = [114(1+1)-4^0](1+1)$
$2\sqrt{457} = (1 + 1)\sqrt{4(114)+(1+1)^0}$
$460 = 4(115) = 4[(1+1)^0+114]$
$16 = 4^2 = 4^{1+1}$
$8 = 4(1+1)$
$3 = -(1+1)^0+4$
$14 = 10^1+4$
$83 = 40(1+1)+[-(1+1)^0+4]$
$85 = 40(1+1)+[(1+1)^0+4]$
$87 = 4(11)(1+1)-4^0$

Of course, those prime numerals in the hint follow multiples of $4$, so, each may be expressed as a sum of two integer squares.  Maybe, these, too, involve easy patterns of $4$'s and $1$'s.

Comment: This is not the correct answer.Try to think if you had a triangle ABC what the conclusion would be.

Comment: AB^3 = AC^3 + BC^3.  There are no such integer solutions. I was wondering that you had a physical model for such numbers. Now, I don't think so. My interest in such numbers is a cute little "double" M-theory I've been working on, which keys in on the dimensions from 40 to 44.

Comment: The numbers on  the question are not  rational,

Comment: That there are no such integer solutions doesn't alter the fact that AB^3 = AC^3 + BC^3.

Answer (score 0):

Some initial hallucinations:
Let's split the numbers into two groups by the radical that appears in their expression. Each of these two groups contains two "large" numbers, with integer part close to the radical, and one "small" number.
For the 85-group:

> The two large numbers are $(\lambda x.x^2+(2+1)x)(-1+\sqrt{85})$ and $(\lambda x.x^2+(2-1)x)(1+\sqrt{85})$ and the small number has its parts in a $2:1$ ratio.

For the 457-group:

> The two large numbers are $(\lambda x.x^2+(3+1)x)(-1+\sqrt{457})$ and $(\lambda x.x^2+(3-1)x)(1+\sqrt{457})$ and the small number has its parts in a $3:1$ ratio.

Might there be

> another group consisting of two large numbers, which are $(\lambda x.x^2+(4+1)x)(-1+\sqrt{N})$ and $(\lambda x.x^2+(4-1)x)(1+\sqrt{N})$ for some N, and a small number which has its parts in a $4:1$ ratio?
>  For a given ratio $r$, what would be its relation with $N$?

Comment: This is not the correct answer

Comment: Which of us is closest to the correct path? Does it even make sense to group the numbers this way?

Answer (score 0):

I can see two pairs that

> have the same norm:
>
>
>  $N(454+2\sqrt{457}) = 204288 = N(460+4\sqrt{457})$
>
>  $N(83+\sqrt{85}) = 6804 = N(87+3\sqrt{85})$

but the remaining pair (including the strangely written $14\sqrt{457}+42$) doesn't satisfy this relation. Not sure if this is intended or not.

Comment: This is not the correct answer.